# javascript inheritence why is property left out in some?

Tags: javascript

why is `this.name = name;` in the  Penguin and Emperor classes  and why is `this.numLegs = numLegs;` left out? is it because you can can set those properties if it has it?

```
// original classes
function Animal(name, numLegs) {
    this.name = name;
    this.numLegs = numLegs;
    this.isAlive = true;
}
function Penguin(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.numLegs = 2;
}
function Emperor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.saying = "Waddle waddle";
}

// set up the prototype chain
Penguin.prototype = new Animal();
Emperor.prototype = new Penguin();

var myEmperor = new Emperor("Jules");

//console.log(myEmperor.saying); // should print "Waddle waddle"
//console.log(myEmperor.numLegs); // should print 2
//console.log(myEmperor.isAlive); // should print true
console.log(myEmperor.name);
```

Comment: The answer is because the developer chose not to set that property from an argument in the constructor.  That was simply a design decision.

Comment: Please elaborate a little bit.

Comment: Sorry, But i couldn't find some problems with this script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first class, Animal represents a generic animal. Some animals have 2 legs, some have 4, so when you instantiate a generic animal you need to say how many legs it has. That is why the numLegs parameter is passed to the constructor.

```
var fluffyTheCat = new Animal('Fluffy', 4);
```

The second class represents only the Penguins and as we all know, all penguins have 2 legs. You don't need to say how many legs penguins have, so instead of saying:

```
var pingyThePenguin = new Animal('Pingy', 2);
```

you can say:

```
var pingyThePenguin = new Penguin('Pingy');
```

Emperors are special penguins, that unlike regular penguins also have a saying. But they all have the same saying, so you don't need to pass that to the constructor either.

---

**Slightly off-topic**

The inheritance in your example is slightly broken. You should not have to instantiate the base class to get the prototype for the inheriting one. Specifically:

```
Penguin.prototype = new Animal();
```

is somehow broken.

Instead, you could do something along the lines of:

```
Penguin = new function(name) {
  // inherits from Animal
  Animal.call(this, name,2);
}

Penguin.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);

Emperor = new function(name) {
  // inherits from Penguin
  Penguin.call(this, name);      
  this.saying = "Waddle waddle";
}

Emperor.prototype = Object.create(Penguin.prototype);
```

Answer (score 0):

You use this function

```
var myEmperor = new Emperor("Jules");
```

Which gives the name , but you don't initialize `numlegs`

Example :

```
var myEmperor =new Penguin('ss');
```

Comment: here u created object which handle the numlegs ;

Comment: the object that contains the `numlegs` is part of the prototype, but the property `numlegs` itself is NOT part of the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

The first one called `Animal` is universal so it can have a lots of different legs, in the other one `Penguin` well penguins have 2 legs so that's the reason, and the last one `Emperor` is not an animal and isn't creating an animal that's why it's not creating any legs.